# Use of Taylor theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is twice differentiable real function on $(0,\infty)$ and $A$, $B$, $C$ are supremum of $|f|$, $|f'|$, $|f''|$, respectively on $(0,\infty)$ then what is the relation between $A$,$B$,$C$?

Comment: What did you try? What worked, what did not?

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor theorem, we have that for $x>0$ and $h>0$,
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x) h+\frac{1}{2}f''(t) h^2$$
for some $t\in (x,x+h)$. Hence,
$$|f'(x)|\leq \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}+\frac{|f''(t)| h}{2}\leq
\frac{2A}{h}+\frac{C h}{2}:=F(h)$$
Now it is easy to see that the function $F$ on the right-hand side is minimized at $h=2\sqrt{A/C}$, therefore for any $x>0$
$$|f'(x)|\leq F(2\sqrt{A/C})=2\sqrt{AC}$$ 
which implies that $B\leq 2\sqrt{AC}$.

Comment: Nice considerations.